# How to not return anything with Ransack Search Gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

I'm using the Ransack Gem in my Rails app. When I do a blank search it returns all posts.

How can I limit it to return nothing if blank?

I tried in my view:

```
<% if @q.blank? %>
```

,but still get all posts.

In the controller:

```
 def index

    @q = Post.search(params[:q])
    @posts = @q.result(:distinct => true)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @posts }
    end
  end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
  if !params[:q].blank?
    @q=Post.search(params[:q])
  else
    @q=Post.search({:id_eq => 0})
  end

  @posts = @q.result
```